# How to enable hardware encryption on my Crucial MX500 drive with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, encryption, ssd, arm64

I have a Crucial MX500 1TB drive, and it supports hardware encryption. I need to attach it to my Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 and enable encryption. I also need the drive to be auto attached to the Pi with the saved password during startup. It is not the boot drive. It is just an another drive that is attached to the Pi.